# Gaussian elimination algorithm performance

Tags: matrices, number-theory, elementary-number-theory, algorithms, gaussian-elimination

I am [developing](https://github.com/gazman-sdk/quadratic-sieve) the [quadratic sieve](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_sieve) algorithm and I reached a new bottle neck: The matrix processing.

I been reading quit a lot about this topic and I found many solutions

- [Gaussian elimination](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_elimination): This perhaps the most common approach for this problem. It's running time is $O(N^3)$ above GF (2)
- [Method of Four Russians](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_of_Four_Russians): It optimize the classic **Gaussian elimination** to $O(\frac{N^3}{\log{N}})$ by partition the matrix into small square blocks of size $\log N$. You can read more about it [here](https://martinralbrecht.files.wordpress.com/2011/11/ple.pdf)(section 3.2).
- [Block Wiedemann algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_Wiedemann_algorithm) is used to parallelize the matrix of several machines in order to speed up the process. Here is a good example of such [implementation over GAPP](https://www.cs.umd.edu/~gasarch/TOPICS/factoring/fastgauss.pdf), they use a little bit different algorithm for that.

But non of the above was good enough for me, so I created my own [algorithm](https://github.com/gazman-sdk/quadratic-sieve/blob/master/src/com/gazman/factor/matrix/HashMatrix.java).

It's based on **Gaussian elimination**, but instead of searching for pivot in each column I represent the columns with [hash table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table) and [linked list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linked_list)(This is how HashMap in java is implemented) where each node of the list is stored in **hash table** and contain the pivot index of the original matrix. So I can iterate over all the pivots of column.

When I start to perform **Gaussian elimination** it only takes $O(1)$ to find the first pivot of a column, once I find such pivot I store it in another **hash  table**, so I want pick it for the next column I will operate. Next I iterate over the reset of the pivot of the first column and xor the rows to eliminate all the reset of the pivot of the first column. I do the same trick with the rows, so I got duplicate representation of the matrix, by hash-table rows and columns. This allows me to speed up the row xoring process as I only iterate over the row pivot. The xor operation itself of each node is $O(1)$ but it evolves 2 hash operations and it's by it self quite expensive. And so this is the part where this algorithm fails. Even so that I estimate it's performance as sub-quadratic on average.

I ended up [implementing](https://github.com/gazman-sdk/quadratic-sieve/blob/master/src/com/gazman/factor/matrix/BitMatrix.java) classic **Gaussian elimination** using bit operators and it allows me to process square matrices with up to $10,000$ lines in minutes time. But it's not fast enough for me, my goal is factoring 100 digits number, this require around 1M square matrix size, and this impossible with my current approach.

Is there any other methods that I missed? What is the best non parallel method to solve this problem?

Comment: The complexity of GE in GF(2) is realy O(N^3)?

Comment: @V-X Yes, if you count the number of times you will have to multiply-add during the process you will get $O(N^3)$. First you have $n(N-1)$ in the first step, then $(N-1)(N-2)$ and so on. You end up with $\sum j(j+1)$ which has a cubic sum.

Comment: I think you're mistaken, your method seem to only optimize the search for the pivot. You still have the actual elimination which I don't see how you do to avoid $O(N^3)$ time. I think your code is $O(N^3)$ as you have two nested loops of $N$ length in which you do `xor` which in turn is $O(N)$.

Comment: @skyking it also optimize the xoring as I only take the pivots from the row as there is no point to xor zeroes. This why it's double hash. Actually calculating the true performance here is quite hard task. I did it by manually calculating the actions: Xor cells is 1, reading cell is 1. In my tests it allays been below $x^2$. But as I said it's not a proof and it's hard to tell.

Comment: I still think you're mistaken. $O(N^2)$ is a lower bound, you will at the very least produce the result which is $N^2$ bits of information, in at least half of the cases you will need at least $N^2-1$ bits to represent that.

Comment: @skyking The output is just the combination to get zero row. It's $O(N)$ in the worst case(unlikely to happen), and $O(1)$ in all the rest. Remember with hash map, only the pivot counts. Also consider this: I think its safe to say that in the end all the hash maps will only contain very small amount of pivot(Mostly $1$), you can count it as one in compare to $N$. So all the xor operations beyond some point will be very close to $1$. This is why it's sub-quadratic.

Comment: Maybe you're not talking about the complete GE, but only a tiny part of it. If you want to produce an inverse matrix you're bound to have at least $O(N^2)$ on average for above mentioned reason. Even if there's a part of the algorithm that has lower complexity than that it will not help the averall complexity $O(N^2) + O(N)$ is still $(O(N^2)$.

Comment: @skyking Oh I see. Yeah you are probably right! I forgot about the invert matrix. I try to see if someone found some alternatives for using the invert matrix.

Comment: They always mention the block Lanczos algorithm in this context.

Answer (score 3):

Your approach to Gaussian elimination is fundamentally at odds with the currect state of hardware. You are up against the memory wall, i.e. the fact that floating point operations can be completed at a rate which is far higher than the speed at which data can be retrieved from may memory. By processing your matrix one column at a time, your are constantly experiencing cache misses and you CPU is running at a fraction of the peak rate. A truly enourmous amount of research involving many good people working together for many years, has gone into developing blocked algorithms which facilitate reuse of the data stored in the cache hierarchy.

On a "standard" desktop with a Haswell chip, running at 3.6 GHz a random matrix of dimension $N=10,000$ can be factored using around 4.5 seconds using the dense factorization routine in LAPACK.

It is possible to write fast matrix factorization routines based on Strassens matrix matrix multiplication with roughly $O(N^{2.6})$ complexity, but I cannot recommend this approach due to unresolved stability issues.

So to answer you question, the best sequential algorithms for GE currently available is are implementations of LAPACK's DGETRF/DGETRS which factors and solves general nonsingular linear systems. You should be able to obtain an implementation through www.netlib.org.